# ISP blocking my internet randomly for 10 minutes at a time, because of 'suspicious' activity

Tags: networking, router, internet, isp, wan

So recently I switched to a new ISP where the connection coming into my apartment is Ethernet cable based that connects my router directly with the ISP's router in my building's network room.

Ever since switching, I've had this weird issue that my router would stop getting any WAN signal for exactly 10 minutes and some seconds ! I contacted my ISP and they say that my router apparently sends some 'suspicious' network signal that's bad, which their router doesn't like and so shuts down the port connecting to my router for 10 minutes as a security measure. Their technician said he doesn't know much about this issue but said that he's seen it happen to some TP-Link routers, which I happen to have. He suggested updating my router's firmware, which I did and no it didn't help.

[image]

Anyone know what is probably causing this ?? I've never had this issue before, or have even heard for it ! :/

Comment: Your ISP's tech support can walk you through how to modify the settings for whatever type of `snort`-like Intrusion Detection setup that is on their router.

Comment: Without knowing what "suspicious network signal" he thinks is being sent over Ethernet we cannot really say. It could be your router checking particular sites for updates, a sign that it has been co-opted into a Mirai-style botnet, or it could simply be that your router is sending some network discovery packet of some kind. It is up to your ISP to tell you either that your hardware is not compatible or supported, or to tell you what it is actually doing that is wrong.

Comment: I would assume that "suspicious network signal" is a nice paraphrase for network packets that make a certain service/daemon on the router crash and as they know the problem there is a cron job running every 10 minutes that restarts the service.